# Content-Encoding not displayed in Response header when Accept-Encoding is either gzip or deflate

Tags: apache-2.2, firefox

I am using Firefox and when I set the `Accept-Encoding` to `deflate,gzip` I get `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response header. When I use `Accept-Encoding` as either `deflate` or `gzip` the `Content-Encoding` is removed from the header.

Can anyone please explain me why ? Is there any apache configuration I need to consider ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the RFC it offers details about which values can be used in Accept-Encoding and how a  server tests whether a content-coding is acceptable, according to an Accept-Encoding field, using these rules,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-accept-encoding

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving a .gz file, perhaps you are looking to add an association between the file extension and the desired mime-type with [mod_mime](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding).  The following can be added to the VirtualHost configuration.

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
```

Alternatively, a [more complete example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#precompressed) for serving pre-compressed content involves not just adding the encoding-type but also disabling mod_deflate and resetting the content-type.  This example uses mod_header to add the encoding-type.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist 
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.css" "$1\.css\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist 
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.js" "$1\.js\.gz" [QSA]


    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]


    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header append Content-Encoding gzip

      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & 
      # non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

(Note the above adds DOCUMENT_ROOT to the RewriteCond file path from the referenced sample since I believe it is needed when used in the VirtualHost context from 2.2+.)

Comment: I notice that I linked to documentation for Apache 2.4 while the original question referenced 2.2.  While I haven't tested against 2.2, a cursory review makes me think it should work with 2.2 as well.